# Quick and dirty user interface for app's config file?

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration

I'd like to give my user's a simple Winforms GUI interface so they can view and edit my app's config file, but don't really have time to do a custom, hard coded solution right now.

Also, requirements for configurable settings are in flux in my project right now - would be nice if solution would automatically discover and display new settings added to the config file.

For the user interface, I'm thinking along the lines of a simple, 2 column, key-value grid.  User's could edit fields in the "value" columns, and save them back to the config file.

I'm wondering if it's possible to databind a grid directly to the config file, or via some simple glue logic.

Or maybe there's a Winforms control that already does something similar?

All suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can bind a `PropertyGrid` control to `Settings.Default`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks!  My actual code is:          propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = Properties.Settings.Default;